# Create a Subfolder in Project/Builds from RTC/Jazz-Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, rtc

We have a lot of Build Definitions and i want to create a category or a subfolder to make less mess (what a phrase) in our Project

[image: RTC/Jazz-Plugin]

this image shows only half of our build definitions and i really want to clean up here!

i've tried the context menu (right mouse button) but i didn't find any useful items there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "subfolder" option, for build (for grouping builds together) or even source control (for grouping streams together) in RTC (3, early 4).

The "[Administering Rational Team Concert Builds](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/tadminteambuild.html&scope=null)" only suggests [**tagging builds**](http://Administering%20Rational%20Team%20Concert%20Builds)

> You can tag builds to organize them or identify them for search purposes.
>   You can also select a tag from an existing list of tags.
>   A tag is a single word with no spaces.
>   A build result can have multiple tags associated with it

Update 2015: as mentioned in [Enhancement 217033](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=217033) (even though it was triaged in [Enhancement 303863](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=303863)), also mentioned in [Task 303722](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=303722):

> RTC 4.0.6 has the capability to organize build definitions into build folders.

RTC 5 has that feature fully implemented, as mentioned in [Enhancement 300232](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=300232).

The [OP Martin Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910751/martin-frank) adds this image:

[image]

> Once a folder is created you can drag&drop the build definitions into the desired folder.

Comment: Thank you for your support again! ok, seems like i'll have to tag them ^^

Comment: by the way - nowadays it is possible to create folders and organize your build definitions.... funny, that it's working now ^^

Comment: @MartinFrank with which RTC version? Can you edit the answer?

Comment: maybe one can look up in the Jazz.net pages - there should be an update/releasenotes where this enhancement would be mentioned?

Comment: @MartinFrank OK. I have edited the answer with references which mentions that feature starting in 4.0.6

Comment: fantastic - i am sooooo happy they did it, now i can clean up my work a bit ^^

Comment: i wish i could + your answer again ^^

Comment: @MartinFrank It seems I overwrote your edit. I have restored your picture.

Comment: @MartinFrank on second thought, could you edit this picture and replace it with one where one can *not* see actual jazz server name? ;)

Comment: i saw it - i hope it helps other user to get along better ^^

Comment: fixed the server name - i accientially un-upvoted the question, but re-upvoted it again!